# Is JSON and YAML considered Markup languages?

Tags: linux, json, yaml

I have my Comp Tia Linux+ (XK0-004) exam tomorrow. I purchased the "Compt Tia Linux+ All in one Exam Guide) book off Amazon and this book is contradicting what Google searches are saying regarding JSON and YAML.

The book says clearly in CH 18 Review:

> JSON and YAML are markup languages that may be used for data serialization.
>
> YAML stands for Yet Another Markup Language.

Search results on Stackoverflow:

- JSON is not a markup language: [Is JSON a markup language like XML? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647722/is-json-a-markup-language-like-xml)
- YAML stands for YAML Ain't Markup Language: [If YAML ain't markup language, what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968366/if-yaml-aint-markup-language-what-is-it)

Exact quote from an [answer with +140 from a self proclaimed contributer to creating YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928199/414121):

> "After a few months of us working together, I pointed out that YAML (which most definitely stood for Yet Another Markup Language at that time) was not really a markup language (marking up various elements of a text document) but a serialization language (textual representation of typed/cyclical data graphs). We all liked the name YAML, so we backronymed it to mean YAML Ain't Markup Language."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn about both technologies, I suggest reading their spec:

- YAML: https://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-12-10.html
- JSON: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

What the YAML person said is generally correct: it's less of a *markup* language and more a *notation* for things like objects.
I think JSON's definition kinda says it best:

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

A *markup* language is used for *marking up* text for instance.

The fact that often markup languages are used to define an entire object structure (like HTML, or XML) murky the distinction, but while things like YAML and JSON are only able to define complete structures (even if it's a sub-part of a larger collection, of sorts), while markup can be entirely absent from a document. The reason why in things like HTML an empty document still contains some structure (like `<html> <head> ... </head> <body> ... </body> </html>` is due to constraints added later. Technically, a plain text document with no tags at all is also valid HTML.

Another interesting take is things like [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), which obviously is a markup language, and rarely used to define object-like structures for information interchange.
On the other hand you have [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) ("Tom's own markup language") which calls itself a markup language, but it clearly isn't.

I have yet to see JSON being used as a markup language, same for TOML. YAML can be technically used as a markup language, but there's no need, because there are better solutions. A bunch of markup languages make more or less good object definition languages (such as XML), but using a data definition language for markup is usually a terrible experience. But there are instance where the distinction is exceptionally blurry in general - hence we have a bunch of *markup* languages that kinda do both (like HTML).
To some extent, it depends on the use case. Is the language primarily used for annotations, be it rendering, network communication, etc. but the un-annotated content is the main focus here, then it's a markup language.

If instead the actual content is only regarded as data, less so as a "document", then it's a data definition language, etc.
If markup is missing from a document, it doesn't destroy the document, the content is still there, just perhaps less organized and less readable or parse-able.

In data definition languages like JSON, a set of data doesn't really exist should a structure like JSON be missing with only the content remaining (such as plain text) - that would not be JSON anymore.

In my opinion, the big misnomer is XML. It says in it's name, it's a markup language, but it's pretty much never used as such, instead it's pretty much only used to serialize data. Hence, I think the term "markup language" in names is often used incorrectly. The reason might be (I presume, I don't know for sure) the original intention. XML was originally *intended* as an "extensible markup language" but it ended up being only used for data serialization, and object notation, etc. Another reason might be marketing, etc.

Finally, I'd like to quote this abstract from the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572) *(some words highlighted by me)*:

> 1.3. Relation to JSON
>
> Both JSON and YAML aim to be human readable data **interchange formats**. However, JSON and YAML have different priorities. JSON’s foremost design goal is simplicity and universality. Thus, JSON is trivial to generate and parse, at the cost of reduced human readability. It also uses a lowest common denominator information model, ensuring any JSON data can be easily processed by every modern programming environment.
>
> In contrast, YAML’s foremost design goals are human readability and **support for serializing arbitrary native data structures**. Thus, YAML allows for extremely readable files, but is more complex to generate and parse. In addition, YAML ventures beyond the lowest common denominator data types, requiring more complex processing when crossing between different programming environments.
>
> YAML can therefore be viewed as a natural superset of JSON, offering improved human readability and a more complete information model. This is also the case in practice; every JSON file is also a valid YAML file. This makes it easy to migrate from JSON to YAML if/when the additional features are required.
>
> […]
>
> It may be useful to define a intermediate format between YAML and JSON. Such a format would be trivial to parse (but not very human readable), like JSON. At the same time, it would allow for serializing arbitrary native data structures, like YAML. Such a format might also serve as YAML’s "canonical format". Defining such a “YSON” format (YSON is a Serialized Object Notation) can be done either by enhancing the JSON specification or by restricting the YAML specification. Such a definition is beyond the scope of this specification.

Note the absence of the term "markup language" in that paragraph. Instead it is mentioned how it's an interchange format and designed for data serialization.
In the last part they discuss creating of an intermediary format, that might be better used for whatever the requirements are stated. This further exemplifies the fact that the line between "markup language" and not, isn't clear, and there is sort of a definition "gray zone".

---

In general, I suggest not just "googling for it" but trying to find the definitions, and read what the developers of said technology define. So you completed the googling step, but next time, also read through documentation of it, etc.

And if your book contradicts what the developer says about their technology or product: text books might be wrong, but also the whatever the developer or author defines might make no sense, so don't take both as gospel. If in doubt, learn about both technologies and see how much it is in line with what they say about themselves, or what the text book says. Some text book authors also simply adopt the definition of the developer, etc.

Usually, you can always refer to it using a slightly wider definition. XML and JSON are both certainly object notations and can be used as definition languages.
Things like [OGDL](https://ogdl.org/) simply call themselves an "ordered graph definition language", which would be a valid desciiption for things like XML or pretty much any language that uses tree-like structures, including JSON.

Comment: So from what I'm understanding from your comment is it is possible for YAML to be used as a 'markup language' but that's not its prime function? Also if you were asked on a test "Which of the following is considered markup language?" and two of the choices is YAML and JSON, would you only choose YAML?

Comment: In a test, it is completely irrelevant what other people say which answer to choose. The only thing that is relevant is what the person who grades the test believes the correct answer is, whether that is actually true or not. So, you should give the answer you were being taught.

Comment: @TClapStorm yes, although using YAML as markup language is more a case of "shoehorning it in". JSON is not. YAML is a superset of JSON, but it doesn't turn it into a markup language equivalent to HTML or SGML. The distinction between markup language and not, aren't 100% clear, there is some overlap.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Although I think it's pretty cynical to put it like that, but in general I'd agree. Certainly whatever your course material states should be the correct answer. The course material might be in error (which would make a correct answer on a test technically incorrect), but this not necessarily the fault of the teacher, etc. Languages are being developed further, constantly. Use cases change and featuresets of languages change too over time.

Comment: @TClapStorm btw. your book states: "JSON and YAML are markup languages that may be used for data serialization." I'd say it's the opposite: "JSON and YAML  are data serialization fromats that may be used for markup." However, as I said, using JSON as markup language is like using sound files to store documents. Technically possible, but why would you?